重回帰分析における損失関数式Lの再考
勾配降下法を使ったニュ-ラルネットワ-クで損失関数の一般式がL=1/NΣ(tn-yn)^2で表されていますが、L=(tn-yn)^2 [n=1,2,3,~,N]で表したほうが、∂L/∂Wを導くプロセスに適していると考えますが、如何ですか。
理由
例をあげて説明します。
入力層ノード3バイアス1, 中間層ノード2バイアス1, 出力層ノード1
条件
データ数n：1〜N
X：xn0,xn1,xn2,xn3,tn
W1：w111,w112,w113,w121,w122,w123
バイアス
b11：w011
b12：w012
W2：w221,w222
バイアス
b21：w021
①順伝播
入力層-中間層　
u1=w111xn1+w112xn2+w113xn3+w011xn0
n2=w121xn1+w122xn2+w123xn3+w012xn0
h11=a(u1)
h12=a(u2)
a：活性化関数
中間層-出力層
yn=w221h11+w222h12+w021x0
②逆伝播
損失関数
旧案
L=1/NΣ(tn-yn)^2
∂L/∂yn=-2/NΣ(tn-yn)
新案
L=(tn-yn)^2
∂L/∂yn=-2(tn-yn)
この時、データ数がNの時
勾配は旧式∂L/∂W2=∂L/∂yn・∂yn/∂W2であり、新案
は∂L/∂W2=1/NΣ(∂L/∂yn・∂yn/∂W2)と考えました。
旧案と新安の∂L/∂ynを勾配上式に代入すると考えたとき、∂L/∂ynの1/NとΣの関連が旧式では∂L/∂W2の計算プロセスとして明確に伝わって来ない、従って新案の方が明解で論理的でありニュ-ラルネットワ-クを考える上で適切である。
補足であるがW1の勾配の考え方も同様であり、その後の更新により、最適値w111,w112,w113,w121,w122,w123
バイアスw011,w012
が求まり、最後にW重みを使って推論値が推察可能となる。
その後一晩考え、
L=(tn-yn)^2により∂L/W2を求めた方が計算プロセスに無理が無いと考えましたが、
L=1/NΣ(tn-yn)^2により∂L/∂W2=∂L/∂yn・∂yn/∂W2の一般式で∂yn/∂W2を各々∂L/∂ynに掛けておいて、∂L/∂ynに便乗した∂L/∂ynを合計して平均を求めると考えても良い感じがしました。

python3 タグがついていますが、プログラミングの話というより数学の話な気がします。

重回帰分析を解く上で数学的知識の元、間を埋め、プログラミングに取り組んでいこうと思います。

ちょっとネット検索したところでは「1/N」がない式の記事が複数見つかりました。「重回帰分析で損失関数の一般式」というのはどこの情報でしょうか？

紛らわしくてすみません。
損失関数L=1/NΣ(tn-yn)^2
Lの勾配∂L/∂W2=∂L/∂yn・∂yn/∂W2
この式はディ-プラ-ニング入門Chainerチュ-トリアルのサイトで13章ニュ-ラルネットワ-クの基礎にでてきます。
以上です。

「回答」はあくまで「質問に対する回答(解決策)」を投稿する部分ですので、補足情報はコメント欄または質問を編集して追記するようにしてください。

Chainerの解説では重回帰分析には二乗誤差、ニューラルネットワークには平均二乗誤差が使用されていますね。ところで「L=(tn-yn)^2 [n=1,2,3,~,N]」というのは何を表しているのでしょうか。

重回帰分析からニュ-ラルネットワ-クに変更します。ニュ-ラルネットワ-クでは二乗誤差を用いた方が計算過程を説明するのに適していることを提案します。

L=(tn-yn)^2[n=1,2,3,~,N]は二乗誤差です。
